# ReactJS starter kit and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap with ReactJS. I started with the react-starter-kit (https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) and installed react-bootstrap. After installing, I tried creating some simple buttons to see if it worked, but they don't look correct. I also saw this link, https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/179, but no luck.

I tried doing this:

```
/*! React Starter Kit | MIT License | http://www.reactstarterkit.com/ */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button, ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap';

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large">Large button</Button>
              <Button bsSize="large">Large button</Button>
              <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="xsmall">Extra small button</Button>
            </ButtonToolbar>
          </div>
        //<button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-sm">Small Info Button</button>

    );
  }

}

export default Header;
```

[image]

I tried it with the commented out line as well, but I wasn't able to get that to work either.

Does anyone know why these buttons with Bootstrap aren't being rendered correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshot indicates no CSS is being applied. As far as I can tell, `react-bootstrap` doesn't come packaged with styles. You'll have to pull in the CSS from `bootstrap` itself.

The easiest way to test is to drop the following into your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```